# Semiconductors, diode in reverse bias

Tags: semiconductor-physics

When a diode is connected in reverse bias to a battery, the negative charge from the $n$ side should flow through the battery to the $p$ side, but that doesn't happen because of the negative captions present at the $p$ side.

Or at least this is the justification for it I found,

But actually, both $p$ and $n$ sides are electrically neutral, it is not like the $p$ side has a net negative charge.

So what is actually going on here?

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the more confusing things in semiconductor physics. Indeed, *undepleted* p-type semiconductor is electrically neutral: the positive hole charge cancels the excess negative charge of the acceptor nuclei.

But at a junction, there's a depletion zone. Depleted p-type semiconductor has a negative charge: there are no holes present to neutralize the charge of the acceptor nuclei. Similarly, depleted n-type has a positive charge.

Answer (score 1):

When the diode is not connected then the two currents flowing within the diode cancel out. Recombination current and thermal generation current. thermal generation current does not depend on the volatge applied, however recombination current does. When the diode is reverse biased then the recombination current decreases, A very small current, thermal geneation current does flow.